# WPF bolder than bold

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a text more bold than bold so I tried other enum values for `FontWeight`, but all of them seem to yield the same result

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontWeight="Black"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontWeight="UltraBlack"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontWeight="UltraBold"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the font extra bold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of distinct weights that you’ll get will depend on the font.  Many fonts have just two weights–Normal and Bold.  The weight value specified in the FontWeight setting is just a request.  Windows will return a font whose weight best matches the requested weight.

Comment: And `ExtraBlack` and `UltraBlack` are the boldest that are exist https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontweights(v=vs.110).aspx